# Как передать переменную "progress" из фрагмента в активити?

Tags: android

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SeekBar seekbar1 = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
        seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {





            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

        });
    }

}





public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentManager manager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        initFragment2();
    }

    private void initFragment2() {
        transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, new Fragment2());
        transaction.commit();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте переменную sendProgress в поле класса

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment { 
private int sendProgress = 0;
....
```

В методе onProgressChanged

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {

sendProgress = progress;

}
```

Далее изучаем статью в официальной [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) и с помощью интерфейса передаем значение переменной в Activity.

Comment: Можете рассказать по подробней - как принять переменную в Активити ?